# Align item in box [Jetpack Compose]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to set `ic_remove_selected_photo` at the TopEnd of the box

[image]

What I have achieved:

[image]

Code:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.size(90.dp).padding(7.dp)) {
    Image(
        bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(80.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )

    IconButton(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd).size(10.dp)) {
        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_remove_selected_photo))
    }
}
```

How I can set `remove icon` on the image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

```
@Composable
fun ImageWithCloseButton() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(LightGray)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .size(88.dp),
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
            ),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(Black)
                .size(80.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
        IconButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(White)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .size(16.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Close,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those who are looking for just Alignment.Start or Alignment.End and wondering why they are not working, use Alignment.CenterStart and Alignment.CenterEnd

Answer (score 4):

Use `contentAlignment`:

```
@Composable
fun ImageWithCloseButton() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(LightGray)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .size(88.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground,
            ),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(Black)
                .size(80.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )
        IconButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(White)
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .size(16.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Close,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    }
}
```